# How can I check if a CSV or multiselect field CONTAINS one or more values from another CSV or multiselect field?

Tags: infopath, no-code-solution

I need an InfoPath 2013 codeless solution (i.e., rules-based, tho they can be complex) to the problem I'm having.
As a very simplified example of my challenge, suppose I have two lists that contain a CSV (comma separated values) plain text field, and the first table also has a name field. e.g.:

**LIST1**

**Name1: Steve

**Field1:  apples, oranges, pickles, tomatoes

**LIST2**

**Field2: oranges, lettuce

My InfoPath form is created for List2 and has a data connection to List1 to bring in the needed fields. **I need to return Name1 (“Steve”) if Field1 contains any of the values in Field2.**

**If Field2 only had one value**, then it would be a simple query like “Set Distro to Name1", using a filter like "Field1 CONTAINS Field2”.

*The problem is that Field2 contains multiple values and some of those values may not be in Field1, or may be in a different order.
I need to return the Name1 field any time at least one of the values in Field2 is found in Field1.*

**Bonus information:**

- The items in both Field1 and Field2 may change frequently
- Field1 could contain 15 or more values, and Field2 could easily
  contain 5 or  more values
- We can add new fields to either/both LIST1 or LIST2 if needed
- We can use SharePoint designer if needed, but I have found InfoPath
  processes  code much faster than the workflows (which are already
  rather large)
- Field1 and Field2 are actually populated from a multi-select text box
  using *"substring(eval(eval(Value[. != ""], 'concat(",", .)'), ".."),
  2)"*
- I have tried using something like the nested evals formulas (above)
  to check each value in Field2. e.g., Field1 CONTAINS *substring(eval(eval(Value[. != ""], 'concat(",", .)'), ".."), 2)* but that didn't work
- I have thought of other possible approaches, but they all hinge on
  being able to walk thru Field2 one value at a time... which is my
  core problem

Answer (score 0):

I did not know you could change the select "VALUE" (when selecting a multi-select group) to selecting ANY OCCURRENCE OF VALUE or selecting ALL OCCURRENCES OF VALUE... not to mention the "sum" and "count" options! Once I had that piece, I was able to set up a rule to run whenever the multi-select field changed, and update the distribution list accordingly.

The ANY OCCURRENCE OF VALUE effectively lets you check each value in the multi-select control against the other multi-select field's VALUEs... DONE!